# Gradle not recognizing Java 10+ methods

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

so i tried to use methods `List.copyOf` and `Collectors.toUnmodifiableList` but both methods are not getting recognized by gradle hence compiling fails, but they are recognized in the IDE.

I checked everything and everything is using Java 11; project bytecode, sdk, gradle jvm, ... I also tried upgrading Gradle (version 5.6.2) but that did not fix the problem. I am running Java 11.0.4 by AdoptOpenJDK.

[build.gradle](https://haste.ymastersk.net/jiserojici.gradle)

Example of using both methods:

```java
return getGuilds().stream()
        .filter(guild -> users.stream().allMatch(guild::isMember))
        .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

return List.copyOf(buckets.values()); //both methods are unrecognized
```

The error(s) gradle is throwing:

```
            return List.copyOf(buckets.values());
                       ^
  symbol:   method copyOf(Collection<IBucket>)
  location: interface List
```

Here are contents of my gradle file:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar
import com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.BintrayExtension
import com.jfrog.bintray.gradle.tasks.BintrayUploadTask
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
import java.util.*

plugins {
    signing
    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`

    id("com.jfrog.bintray") version "1.8.4"
    id("com.github.ben-manes.versions") version "0.24.0"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "5.1.0"
}

val versionObj = Version(major = "2", minor = "1", revision = "6")

project.group = "me.canelex"
project.version = "$versionObj"
val archivesBaseName = "JDA"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

configure<SourceSetContainer> {
    register("examples") {
        java.srcDir("src/examples/java")
        compileClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets["main"].output
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    /* ABI dependencies */

    //Code safety
    api("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2")
    api("org.jetbrains:annotations:17.0.0")

    //Logger
    api("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.0-alpha0")

    //Web Connection Support
    api("com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.9")
    api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.1")

    /* Internal dependencies */

    //General Utility
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")
    implementation("net.sf.trove4j:trove4j:3.0.3")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.0.pr2")

    //Sets the dependencies for the examples
    configurations.asMap["examplesCompile"] = configurations["apiElements"]
    configurations.asMap["examplesRuntime"] = configurations["implementation"]

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.1")
}

val bintrayUpload: BintrayUploadTask by tasks
val compileJava: JavaCompile by tasks
val shadowJar: ShadowJar by tasks
val javadoc: Javadoc by tasks
val jar: Jar by tasks
val build: Task by tasks
val test: Test by tasks
val check: Task by tasks

shadowJar.classifier = ""

val sourcesForRelease = task<Copy>("sourcesForRelease") {
    from("src/main/java") {
        include("**/JDAInfo.java")
        val tokens = mapOf(
                "versionMajor" to versionObj.major,
                "versionMinor" to versionObj.minor,
                "versionRevision" to versionObj.revision
        )
        filter<ReplaceTokens>(mapOf("tokens" to tokens))
    }
    into("build/filteredSrc")

    includeEmptyDirs = false
}

val generateJavaSources = task<SourceTask>("generateJavaSources") {
    val javaSources = sourceSets["main"].allJava.filter {
        it.name != "JDAInfo.java"
    }.asFileTree

    source = javaSources + fileTree(sourcesForRelease.destinationDir)

    dependsOn(sourcesForRelease)
}

val sourcesJar = task<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
    classifier = "sources"
    from("src/main/java") {
        exclude("**/JDAInfo.java")
    }
    from(sourcesForRelease.destinationDir)

    dependsOn(sourcesForRelease)
}

val javadocJar = task<Jar>("javadocJar") {
    dependsOn(javadoc)
    classifier = "javadoc"
    from(javadoc.destinationDir)
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val arguments = mutableListOf("-Xlint:deprecation", "-Xlint:unchecked")
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.isIncremental = true
    if (JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible) doFirst {
        arguments += "--release"
        arguments += "8"
    }
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = arguments
    }
}

compileJava.apply {
    source = generateJavaSources.source
    dependsOn(generateJavaSources)
}

jar.apply {
    baseName = project.name
    manifest.attributes(mapOf(
            "Implementation-Version" to version,
            "Automatic-Module-Name" to "me.canelex.jda"))
}

javadoc.apply {
    isFailOnError = false
    options.memberLevel = JavadocMemberLevel.PUBLIC
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"

    if (options is StandardJavadocDocletOptions) {
        val opt = options as StandardJavadocDocletOptions
        opt.author()
        opt.tags("incubating:a:Incubating:")
        opt.links(
                "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/",
                "https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/",
                "https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/")
        if (JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible) {
            opt.addBooleanOption("html5", true)
            opt.addStringOption("-release", "8")
        }
        if (JavaVersion.current().isJava11Compatible) {
            opt.addBooleanOption("-no-module-directories", true)
        }
    }

    //jda internals
    exclude("me/canelex/jda/internal")
}

build.apply {
    dependsOn(jar)
    dependsOn(javadocJar)
    dependsOn(sourcesJar)
    dependsOn(shadowJar)

    javadocJar.mustRunAfter(jar)
    sourcesJar.mustRunAfter(javadocJar)
    shadowJar.mustRunAfter(sourcesJar)
}

bintrayUpload.apply {
    dependsOn(build)
}

test.apply {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    failFast = true
}

publishing {
    publications {
        register("BintrayRelease", MavenPublication::class) {
            from(components["java"])

            artifactId = archivesBaseName
            groupId = project.group as String
            version = project.version as String

            artifact(javadocJar)
            artifact(sourcesJar)
        }
    }
}

class Version(
        val major: String,
        val minor: String,
        val revision: String) {
    override fun toString() = "$major.$minor.$revision"
}
```

Comment: give us some details on your project, maybe even build.gradle or alike

Comment: If you say that the problem is with gradle, it would be helpful to see your build.gradle

Comment: [Here](https://haste.ymastersk.net/jiserojici.gradle).

Comment: All relevant info has to be present in the question: you're going to change your file in the future, but the question must not become stale because of that. Please include a [mcve] in the question body.

Comment: We understand that you have java code that uses Java 11. But you have to give us details of your *build setup*. Again: read [mcve]. And then enhance your question, do not provide such information in comments!

Comment: I have edited the question so i hope you will be happy now.

Comment: @SeboMolnár, no, I won't be happy by samples of code that don't compile, since your question is about gradle file, and so the question must've contain at least some exerpts from it. In fact, if you'd gone through the trouble of preparing a [mcve], you would find what was wrong with it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part of your build file:

```
tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    val arguments = mutableListOf("-Xlint:deprecation", "-Xlint:unchecked")
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.isIncremental = true
    if (JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible) doFirst {
        arguments += "--release"
        arguments += "8"
    }
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = arguments
    }
}
```

You are instructing Gradle to compile using the Java 8 API with `--release 8` flag. And since the methods you are using are not present in Java 8 (for instance, `List.copyOf` was introduced in Java 10), it fails.

If you don't need Java 8 compatibility, remove the release flag. If you do, then code against that SDK.